# How to enable HTTP server for Mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

As per my understanding when we run mongod.exe in windows , in addition to starting database server , it also sets up a basic HTTP server on port 1000 higher than the main port(in my case its default 27017)

But when I enter http://localhost:28017/ in browser, nothing gets displayed.

what needs to modified/configured to enable HTTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first run it

```
mongod --httpinterface
```

then access it via http

```
http://localhost:28017/
```

Comment: It seems do not work anymore. db version v3.6.4 - `Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--httpinterface'`